# How to get data from MongoDB version 3.4 using Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, crud

I am trying to collect data from my mongodb in java, I need to use select query and put it in jtextarea. Select Query will be filled with combo box element.

Here is the code:

/**** Connect to MongoDB ****/

```
MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017");
MongoClient mClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);

/**** Get database ****/
MongoDatabase db = mClient.getDatabase("productDB");

mClient.getAddress();
/**** Get collection / table from 'productDB' ****/
MongoCollection<Document> tableCollection = db.getCollection("local");
/**** Find and display ****/
Document whereQuery = new Document();
whereQuery.put("Product Category",categoryCB.getSelectedIndex());



MongoCursor<Document> cursor = tableCollection.find(whereQuery);
mClient.close();
```

In tableCollection.find shows:

> cannot convert from FindIterable to MongoCursor

Is there any way to do this differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found code for this problem and it works, main part is in code below

```
mClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
db = mClient.getDatabase("Your Database Name");

tableCollection = db.getCollection("Your Table Name");
whereQuery = new Document();

whereQuery.put("Your Attribute", typeCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
iterator=tableCollection.find(whereQuery);
cursor = iterator.iterator();

while (cursor.hasNext()) 
{
      /*put your code here*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to receive a *FindIterable* object in a *MongoCursor* reference.

Change thetype of the reference variable '**cursor**' from **MongoCursor** to **FindIterable** or its supertype **MongoIterable**.

```
FindIterable<Document> cursor = tableCollection.find(whereQuery);
```

(or)

```
MongoIterable<Document> cursor = tableCollection.find(whereQuery);
```

Comment: your code doesn't show anything, i tried to put it in jtextarea but cannot get result, by the way thank you for your effort :).

Comment: You have to iterate over the result to get your data.

Comment: How to do that? i am new at java and i do not like Java at all :D.